# Do you "put on" a spare tire?

Tags: grammaticality, speech

Suppose you want to change a flat tire. What is the right/common sentence to say that you put the spare tire in place of the flat tire? From the web I see that the sentence "Put on the spare tire" is used. However, I do not see such an application for the verb "put on" in my dictionary (it is mainly used for wearing clothes).

Comment: You could commonly say I put on a second coat of house paint, put on some sunscreen, put on a happy face. The spare tire is mounted, and put is a general word for placing things onto other things.

Comment: Without taking away from your version, I'd actually say put a spare tire *on*, or would leave 'what I put on' to the imagination, saying I changed the tire.

Comment: In the area where I live (Michigan), we mount a spare tire.  (I have no idea how widespread that terminology is, so this is just a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass In the U.K. I have not heard of anyone mounting a tyre ... unless perhaps they climb on too of a tyre :-) To my ears: take off the old tyre and put on a new one sounds fine.

Comment: BTW we do say things like  *Since I started eating so many chocolate bars and crisps I have put on spare tyre.*

Comment: @YosefBaskin - "Mounting" a tire is the process of installing the tire on the rim.  A "spare tire" (slightly misnamed, as it's really a spare rim+tire) is generally "put on", or, if you want to sound technical, "installed".

Comment: I put on a spare tire means: I put a spare tire on the car. That's typical English trickiness. By the way: put on a spare tire and put a spare tire on are the same thing. You take the verb, drop the object of the phrase and add on to the verb...Yes, mount is also used in AmE.

Comment: @Lambie - Actually, "I put on a spare tire" means that you ate too much and didn't exercise enough.

Comment: I can imagine someone fluent in vocabulary to talk about clothes and fashion say things in terms of clothing all the time. If you're comfortable with saying "take off the flat tire", then saying "put on a spare tire" sounds colloquially natural to me. Why does it have to be just one word?

Comment: @Hot Licks In my opinion, jokes like yours do a disservice to non-native speakers because they simply don't get them. So, oneupmanship vis-à-vis those of us who are native speakers may be funny to us but not to them. But in this day and age, wtf cares, right? It's all about competition. How can I "get" the other person.....

Comment: @Lambie - When you use terms like "spare tire" you are inevitably going to run into meanings other than the most literal one.  It's good to develop a "feel" for what expressions are apt to have idiomatic meanings, or at least learn to not be terribly surprised when they do.

Comment: @HotLicks You know what I meant. No need to distort it. My feel for idioms is just fine.  But "we need" to  watch our wording to non-native speakers.  How about a little [caveat, joke] or [joke] or [idiom]. By the way, never in all my born days (southern AmE) have I heard a person or mechanic say: install a spare tire (tyre, BrE). It just ain't said.

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

I *replaced* the flat tire with the spare tire.

Or more colloquially,

I *swapped in* the spare tire for the flat tire.

Comment: I think OP is asking two things: whether saying "put on" is proper, and what to say "put the spare tire in place of the flat tire" by using one verb. What do you say, in step-by-step sequence?

Answer (score 1):

"**Put on**" is perfectly acceptable and very commonly used. I wouldn't feel the need to search for a substitute phrase, although "replaced" would work.

The colloquial use of "put on a spare tire" means gaining weight around the midsection (hips).

"Put on" is used in a variety of ways. You can put on a spare tire, put on a show, put on a pair of shoes or put on a coat of paint.

Comment: Are you putting me on??

Answer (score -1):

I think this is really "put" rather than "put on" which means something totally different.

Definition of put from dictionary.com
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/put

put
verb (used with object), put, put·ting
to move or place (anything) so as to get it into or out of a specific location or position:

to put a book on the shelf.

Comment: Welcome ClayB.  Usually people giving answers don't take screenshots of text and paste them as images.  I would recommend editing your answer by putting the text in the block quote format.

Comment: I don't think any speaker would find acceptable "I put a spare tire"

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_CE7GqqrvY

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - "Did you see what Fred was doing?  He was doing shot put with a bowling ball!"  "That's nothing.  I put a spare tire!"

Comment: @HotLicks "Put on a happy face" and "Take off the gloomy mask". I think the same goes well with the tire thing.